# How to update the windows store app logo?

Tags: windows, xamarin.forms, windows-store-apps

I successfully uploaded 2 windows apps to windows store. In the initial publish, I forget to select the windows store logos. So I update the app again with the store logo. But after completing the latest update still showing the default xamarin logo.

[image]

I created the windows app using **xamarin forms** and I set the store logo on the **package.appxmanifest** file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How long have you waited after submitting the update? Some changes take up to a business week to be reflected in the store.

Comment: @IInspectable Last update was live on 8/9/2018, 12 days are over after that. Still showing the dummy icons in store.

Comment: @IInspectable You are correct, now the app icons are updated, can you please post it as your answer.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), that's perfectly fine. Since you have all the information (duration, or screenshots even), you are in a far better position to do so, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For windows store, some changes like store logo updation take up to a business week(or more) to be reflected in the store. That is the reason behind this issue.